# Count of td (table) using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr class="row-1 row-first">
<td><div class="inside">Text</div></td>
<td><div class="inside">Text</div></td>
<td><div class="inside">Text</div></td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-2">
<td><div class="inside"></div></td>
<td><div class="inside">Text</div></td>
<td><div class="inside">Text</div></td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-3 row-last">
<td><div class="inside"></div></td>
<td><div class="inside">Text</div></td>
<td><div class="inside">Text</div></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

That is my HTML.. I want to know the count of td's which does not have an empty div (with class="inside") in jQuery? How do I go about it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this, with the [`has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/), [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/), and [`empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selectors:

```
$('td:not(:has(div.inside:empty))').length;
```

Comment: I have a big selector line before the table comes into the html. classes -> .page-community-members .views-view-grid.grid-8... Shall I include it in the selector like this???  $('.page-community-members .views-view-grid.grid-8 td:not(:has(div.inside:empty))').length;

Comment: Can i use it this way? $('.page-community-members .views-view-grid.grid-8 td:not(:has(div.inside:empty))').length;

Answer (score 4):

Made a shorter version:

```
$("td div.inside:not(:empty)").length;
```

example here: http://jsfiddle.net/j7ucY/1/

Comment: -1, It IS shorter, but it leaves out the class selector completely, and it will select the `<div>`s, not `<td>`s. You never know, in the actual application there might be multiple elements inside the table cells.

Comment: sorry, totally missed out on the class. added it now and its still 1 selector shorter than the other solution.

Comment: This will break if there is, for instance, a `br` or an `img` element within the div, since they are inherently empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td div.inside').filter(function(idx){
    return $(this).text() != ""
 }).length;
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rwkwY/)